# Laravel vue update data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have code below where my data refresh every 5sec

```
    methods:{
        update() {
           // my update info goes here
        },
        getInfo: function() { // here i'm getting current data from server (database)
                        let user_id = this.user.id;
                        axios.get('/api/show/'+ user_id).then((response) => {
                            this.info = response.data;
                            this.profile=Object.assign({},this.info);
                        });
                        setTimeout(this.getInfo, 5000);
                    },
        }
},
ready() {
   this.getInfo();
}
```

the problem with this code is every 5sec 1 request goes to my back-end (it take lots of server *imagine 100 users seeing the same page see how many requests goes to server each second).

So I'm looking for another option to refresh my data only when my update request `update() {` gets successful, in that way my data will refresh only when data has changed in database.

Any idea?

## Update

For better understanding of what I try to do...

[image: one]

Comment: I think it's better to use web sockets here so you could just listen for and react to events from the server. Laravel has built in functionality for it.

Comment: @Wreigh updated my question try to explain it better.